# How to efficiently merge hashes by key

Tags: ruby

I have the following array

```
 [ {"date"=>"July 2013", "view"=>12245}, 
   {"date"=>"July 2013", "click"=>916}, 
   {"date"=>"August 2013", "view"=>34889}, 
   {"date"=>"August 2013", "click"=>2012} ]
```

And here is the desired output:

```
 [ {"date"=>"July 2013", "view"=>12245, "click"=>916},
   {"date"=>"August 2013", "view"=>34889, "click"=>2012} ]
```

What would be the most efficient implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar = [ {"date"=>"July 2013", "view"=>12245}, 
   {"date"=>"July 2013", "click"=>916}, 
   {"date"=>"August 2013", "view"=>34889}, 
   {"date"=>"August 2013", "click"=>2012} ]

ar.group_by{|h| h["date"]}.map{|k,v| v.inject(:merge)}
# => [{"date"=>"July 2013", "view"=>12245, "click"=>916},
#     {"date"=>"August 2013", "view"=>34889, "click"=>2012}]
```